2000s kids TV show with elemental powers
There was a kids show in the 2000s that started with a girl that hid in a tree and got tree/wood powers from it. There was also a fireboy who was with the bad guys and eventually joined the tree girl, who by that time had found other kids with elemental powers. The series ended with them all joining to make a golden dragon.

Sounds a bit like https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205679/show-about-5-teens-who-all-have-elemental-powers-and-turn-into-different-humanoi.

@FuzzyBoots - Interesting, but betting totes not. How many girls can turn into trees and fuse into dragons that's not Yu-gi-oh? Hey, jake, are you Australian? ... Also Master Raindrop is an unaccepted answer on https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204885

@Malady: Well, that's embarrassing, being that that's my answer. :-D

Master Raindrop (Wikipedia article), found the fanwiki by Googling "tree magic fuse gold dragon cartoon":
https://masterraindrop0.fandom.com/wiki/Shao_Yen

She fainted and the rest of the flower spontaneously self-submerged under the earth and replants the magical tree around Shao Yen, what turns her into wood, revealing her as the wood element.

She remains that way throughout the entire series, until she "sacrifices" herself to revive the Golden Dragon, who brings her and the other elements back because Master Yun was sad to lose his friends.

